# I want to create a community specific to the sector in which I do business. Can a freelancer do this for me?

Tags: user-behavior, small-communities, user-engagement

I want to establish a PDF magazine, Linkedin, Facebook, and Telegram Group where I share sectoral news. Can a freelancer do these if I put a job advertisement in freelancer networks?
Can those who have tried this before share their difficulties and experiences?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely hire a freelancer to help you establish a PDF magazine, LinkedIn, Facebook, and Telegram group. You can post a job advertisement on various freelancer networks such as Freelancer, Upwork, and Fiverr to find a suitable candidate for the job. Freelancers can help you with designing the magazine, creating social media pages, and managing the groups. However, it’s important to note that the quality of work may vary depending on the freelancer’s experience and expertise.

To get started, you can create a detailed job description that outlines your requirements and expectations. This will help you attract the right candidates for the job. You can also specify the budget and timeline for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I created a community over on Skool platform. I have some IT knowledge which maybe makes it easier for me, but it also probably depends on what you want to do with the community.